# Phonegap plugins only work in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm currently developing a complex Application in Phonegap.
I want to use the Plugin "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner", which works fine in index.html, in the file add.html, where it doesn't work. When I duplicate index.html and call its duplicate index2.html and create a link from index.html to index2.html like this (I use bootstrap)

```html
<li role="presentation" style="padding: 5px;" onClick="redirect('index2.html')"><a href="#">index2</a></li>
```

it doesn't work anymore.

I am using the latest Version of Phonegap, everything was downloaded a few days ago.

If you need more code, here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/niklasApps/GrocerieOrganizer

Answer (score 0):

Check cordova.js reference in add.html file it is "js/cordova.js" but it has to be "cordova.js".